# setRightBarButtonItems:animated not supported in ios4

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

The method `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:` for a `UINavigationItem` is not supported in iOS4.

How could I rewrite this code to add 2 buttons on the right in the bar ?

```
[viewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:helpButton, settingsButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the button's alpha to 0 before you add it to the view, and then animate it's value to 1.0.

```
//..Create the buttons
//Make it invisible
helpButton.alpha = 0.0;
settingsButton.alpha = 0.0

//Add them to the navBar
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:helpButton];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:settingsButton];

//Animate it to 1.0
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void) {
      helpButton.alpha = 1.0;
      settingsButton.alpha = 1.0
    }];
```

Comment: So, should I use addSubview, and what's the best way to display them on the right ?

Comment: Just set the appropriate frames

Comment: It's something about (280,5) - the center, i mean

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I get a Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIBarButtonItem *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'. Should I use a UIView a normal UIBUtton rather than a UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: I do it that way, just Custom UiButtons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display more than one button in iOS4, you have to create them manually.

For example you can set the titleView to a custom view and do whatever you want there by overriding setTitle of the ViewController:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
        UIView *titleView = (UIView *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
        if(!titleView)
        {
            titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40.0)];
            titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
        }
}
```

And you need to use a `UIButton` instead of an `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a [titleView release]; line after the self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView; line since you alloc'ed and init'ed the titleView 3 lines previous?

Comment: I'm so used to ARC, that I almost forgot that retain / release exists :) If you're not using ARC you have to insert a release of course.

Comment: You did not talk about buttons. You talked about titles